# DIfference between Modules and Namespaces in F#

Tags: .net, f#, namespaces, module

I have a problem in understanding the exact difference between modules and namespaces in F# and when using one or the other.
Well, they both are considered in order to incapsulate code and define a hierarchy to get our projects well organized.

Modules have many features: they can contain values, types of all kinds and these elements can be defined `public`, `protected` or `internal` too.

But, when using modules?

I understood also that modules are finally mapped as classes in MSIL (Intermediate Language). So a module is a class, is a type....
My doubts' magnitude improve....

When using modules???
Are they useful?

D. Syme also argues that modules are extensible, so I assume they are like namespaces from this point of view.

I cannot understand the reason to use them.

Thankyou

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One major difference:

.NET namespaces cannot hold **values** (let definitions)  while modules can.

In the IL/Bytecode level, a module is compiled to a .NET class, not a .NET namespace.

**When to use modules?**

For a small and specific task, F# and other FPs usually follow the pattern of bottom up programming: you decompose your task into a set of small functions and then you group these functions into a module.

The answer is that it is just so natural to use a module to group a set of related functions and other F# values and types together.

While a namespace is used to group bigger things: e.g. all classes for Matrix operations.

**Module is not a static class (in C# sense)**
Modules can hold special F# values, e.g. curried functions; while a static class cannot.

Comment: @Yin, could you provide a reference for saying that "a module is compiled to a .NET class"? Thanks.

Comment: @Thr4wn I use .net reflector to look at the c# version of the code.

Answer (score 6):

As Yin Zhu says, modules can hold values.  And you can open modules like namespaces.  These two features together are why in F# you can do things like

```
let z = max x y
```

whereas in a language like C# you'd always have to say something like

```
var z = Math.Max(x,y)
//      ^^^^^   can't call methods from elsewhere without a qualifier
```

and use a qualified name (`SomeClass.Method`) rather than just a name (`letBoundFunction`).  So you can use modules when you want people to be able to open you module `Foo` and call `bar` by just saying `bar` rather than `Foo.bar` everywhere.  (This is especially useful for operators, e.g. if you define a bunch of user-defined operators (such as `+++` or whatnot) in a library, by putting them in a module, people can open the module and then just use e.g. `x +++ y` rather than cumbersome stuff like `(Foo.+++) x y` or whatever.)

Note that while F# puts code in a .fs file in a module (with the name of the file) by default, you can change this by having the first code in the file be a namespace declaration, e.g.

```
namespace Yadda
// declare some types or whatnot, they go in namespace Yadda
```

or by declaring your own module

```
module Blah
// stuff goes in Blah module
```

at the top of the file.

Comment: Thank you Brian you were really helpful

Comment: Have to downvote this historic answer as it's no longer correct. As of C# 6, static using statements  can be used to permit C# code like `var z = Max(x,y)`.